# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, opencv, homebrew

I have developed a program in opencv python on linux and now I am trying to run it on mac.

But now I am getting the following error on running it.
I installed opencv using brew.

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users   /krupanilesh/Desktop/dependencies/gazedev.py
2015-06-23 12:17:00.197 Python[803:16229] -[_NSFullScreenWindow sliders]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x102dcb8c0
2015-06-23 12:17:00.198 Python[803:16229] An uncaught exception was raised
2015-06-23 12:17:00.198 Python[803:16229] -[_NSFullScreenWindow sliders]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x102dcb8c0
2015-06-23 12:17:00.198 Python[803:16229] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff96b4303c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8b34176e objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff96b460ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff96a8be24 ___forwarding___ + 1028
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff96a8b998 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib         0x0000000101f684d8 -[CVView setFrameSize:] + 193
6   libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib         0x0000000101f664b3 cvShowImage + 887
7   libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib         0x0000000101f6506d _ZN2cv6imshowERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEERKNS_11_InputArrayE + 390
8   cv2.so                              0x0000000101888e61 _ZL15pyopencv_imshowP7_objectS0_S0_ + 366
9   Python                              0x00000001000c357d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 24829
10  Python                              0x00000001000c58e3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2115
11  Python                              0x00000001000c5a06 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
12  Python                              0x00000001000ea41e PyRun_FileExFlags + 174
13  Python                              0x00000001000ea6ba PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 458
14  Python                              0x000000010010187d Py_Main + 3101
15  Python                              0x0000000100000f14 Python + 3860
16  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
)
 2015-06-23 12:17:00.199 Python[803:16229] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSFullScreenWindow sliders]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x102dcb8c0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff96b4303c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8b34176e objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff96b460ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff96a8be24 ___forwarding___ + 1028
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff96a8b998 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib         0x0000000101f684d8 -[CVView setFrameSize:] + 193
6   libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib         0x0000000101f664b3 cvShowImage + 887
7   libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib         0x0000000101f6506d _ZN2cv6imshowERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEERKNS_11_InputArrayE + 390
8   cv2.so                              0x0000000101888e61 _ZL15pyopencv_imshowP7_objectS0_S0_ + 366
9   Python                              0x00000001000c357d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 24829
10  Python                              0x00000001000c58e3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2115
11  Python                              0x00000001000c5a06 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
12  Python                              0x00000001000ea41e PyRun_FileExFlags + 174
13  Python                              0x00000001000ea6ba PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 458
14  Python                              0x000000010010187d Py_Main + 3101
15  Python                              0x0000000100000f14 Python + 3860
16  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved the problem myself, for some reason the fullscreen mode does not work on mac, disabling that solved the problem for me.

Comment: Fullscreen mode does work on mac ... but not always! I have a program that works fine on a raspberry Pi, but aborts with trap 6 when trying to enter fullscreen mode after os.system call to mplayer on Mac .... but only the second time through the same section of code (for a second event)! The start up of the program enters full screen mode fine. The first event happens, program exits full screen mode, launches mplayer (in full screen mode), then re-enter full screen mode after mplayer exits. Second event happens, program exits full screen, launches mplayer again in full screen mode, then trap 6